# How to make a div overflow vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a small part of a webpage that will contain a large text and i want it to expand vertically instead of horizontally, I know that is possible to use overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit; both horizontally and vertically with overflow-x and overflow-y, but that doesn't solve my problem cause they either hide the text or put a scrollbar, and I want that div to take all the space that he wants vertically but only the space that he has horizontally, which is half screen on a mobile device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div width="50%" style="background-color:red">
        asdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text will come from a database so I can't break it with line breaks or paragraphs, anyone can help me?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the text using [`word-break: break-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

```css
.container {
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 asdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssasdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

This will do